# how to store data in activity A when activity B is called and came back to activity A

Tags: android, android-studio

In Detail- To store textview's data in activity A and goto activity B do some job and come back to activity A. the stored data should be saved and settext for textviews in activity A. Is there solution for this. I tried onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, but did not worked.

```
   @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
    // killed and restarted.
   if(SelectedDate!=null){
       savedInstanceState.putString("SELECTED_DATE", SelectedDate);
   }
   if(CUST_ID!=null){
       savedInstanceState.putInt("CUST_ID", CUST_ID);
       savedInstanceState.putString("CNAME", CNAME);
       savedInstanceState.putString("CEMAIL", CEMAIL);
   }

   if(notes.getText().toString()!=null && !notes.getText().toString().equals(""))
   {
       addnotes = notes.getText().toString();
       savedInstanceState.putString("ADD_NOTES", addnotes);
   }
}

  @Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    String SelectedDate = savedInstanceState.getString("SELECTED_DATE");
    String cust_id = savedInstanceState.getInt("CUST_ID");
    String addnotes = savedInstanceState.getString("ADD_NOTES");

    if(SelectedDate!="")
    invDate.setText(SelectedDate);
    if(cust_id.toString()!=""){
        customerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cName.setText(CNAME);
        cEmail.setText(CEMAIL);
    }
    if(addnotes!="")
    notes.setText(addnotes);

}
```

Comment: try to save data in onStop and restore in onResume

Comment: Post your code, what you have done?

Comment: use startActivityForResult()

Comment: posted the code written in activity-A

Answer (score 1):

To share data between activities create a [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel) model class that holds your date. Let's say these data are name and the email.

```java
public class FormData implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    // Add here fields you need

    public FormData() {
    }

    protected FormData(Parcel parcel) {
        this.name = parcel.readString();
        this.email = parcel.readString();
        // Restore here other fields. Order of fields is important. Use same order in writeToParcel
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(email);
        // Save here other fields. Order of fields is important. Use same order in constructor
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public static final Creator<FormData> CREATOR = new Creator<FormData>() {

        @Override
        public FormData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new FormData(source);
        }

        @Override
        public FormData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new FormData[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Then from the ActivityA open the ActivityB with [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) method. Inside the ActivityB when form filled up and submit button pressed, you create the FormData class instance, fill up fields with data and return like this

```java
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("result", formData);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Then you can get the results in the ActivityA's onActivityResult method

```java
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check request & result codes before
    FormData formData = data.getParcelableExtra("result");

    formData.getName();
    formData.getEmail();
}
```

Comment: Do we need to start Activity-B using startActivityForResult?

Comment: I didn't get startActivityForResult to call Activity-B, because I need to call it from onBindViewHolder of an adapter

Comment: onActivityResult is never called when came back to activity-A

Comment: You can create the onItemClickListener interface to handle the item clicks. The implementation of this interface will be in activity or fragment. You set this listener to the adapter and invoke when the item view clicked

Answer (score -1):

I see two options:

1. Declare for the Activity A attribute `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in your manifest. This will allow only one instance of the Activity A in your app which means the data user put in the activity will be always available by any comeback to this activity.
2. Save the data in static attributes

Comment: Thanks. But didn't work. I set the attribute for the Activity-A in manifest. Also declared the strings as static

Comment: Maybe you finish your activity A somewhere or affect activity A by working in B?